# Styling primefaces texteditor

Tags: css, primefaces, quill

I am having issues styling the buttons in the Primefaces text editor. I was able to find the documentation here: [link to quill](https://quilljs.com/guides/how-to-customize-quill/). Unfortunately, I can' figure out how to do the styling for a simple dark mode. Every icon and text in the menubar should be white, the background should be dark. So far I've tried inline style, assigning a class. Nothing seems to lead to success. Even primetek itself doesn't seem to be very successful with that.

Minimal reproducible example:

```html
<p:textEditor widgetVar="editor1" value="#{editorView.text}" height="300" />
<p:textEditor
  widgetVar="editor2"
  value="#{editorView.text2}"
  height="300"
  placeholder="Enter your content"
>
  <f:facet name="toolbar">
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <select class="ql-font" />
    </span>
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <button class="ql-bold" />
      <button class="ql-italic" />
      <button class="ql-underline" />
    </span>
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <select class="ql-color" />
      <select class="ql-background" />
    </span>
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <button class="ql-script" value="sub" />
      <button class="ql-script" value="super" />
    </span>
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <button class="ql-code-block" />
    </span>
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <button class="ql-list" value="bullet" />
    </span>
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <button class="ql-link" />
    </span>
  </f:facet>
</p:textEditor>
```

Simply add this code to a JSF-page and try to style the top toolbar with bold, italic, etc.

Comment: I just tried the showcase with the dark Arya theme and it is sort of working. See also https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/8064

Comment: Thank you for answer. The styling in Arya theme looks close to my custom font. The buttons are very dimm. This is a big problem in terms of accessibility.

Comment: Hence the issue